# How to restrict provide user access to specific records inside one app (let's say Insurance -> Employee) and provide all access to another app

Tags: apex, permissions, profile

I want one user `Rahul` to have access to specific records (let's say all employees from India) inside Insurance App. But when he switches app like `Sales` he can see all the employee.
Any idea How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding , this is not possible out of the box in Salesforce.

I would recommend below approach :

1. Create a custom LWC/Aura/Visualforce for displaying records and you can add it as a custom tab.
2. App name can be fetched in Apex using [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IDhRQAW) approach.(Assuming these apps are in LEX)
3. In Apex , fetch records based on the criteria and display on UI.

You can choose the desired access level(OWD) for the user to be applied in general and view/update(*create is not mentioned in question*) the records based on the logic in apex.